# How to use json array in WHERE IN clause in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres query like this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status IN (2,1);
```

This is part of a big query, but I am facing an issue with the WHERE IN part here. I am using this query inside a function and the input parameters are in JSON format. Now the status values I am getting in in the form of a JSON array and it will be like `status=[2,1]`. I need to use this array in the WHERE clause in the query and not sure how to do that. Currently, I am using like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status IN (array([2,1]));
```

But this is giving me an error. The status column is of `smallint` data type. I know this is simple, but I am very much new to Postgres and could not figure out any method to use the JSON array in WHERE IN clause. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `WHERE status IN (array[2,1])`. Remove the extra parentheses.

Comment: `status = any(array[2,1])`